# DispatcherServlet in Springboot is not working

Tags: spring-mvc, dispatcher, request-mapping, spring-boot-3

In Springboot 3.0
We have registered a servlet ss000Action that extends from HttpServlet and does nothing inside.
Use ServletRegistrationBean to register ss000Action servlet with

```
addUrlMappings("/sp/*")
setLoadOnStartup(1)
```

Create ss0001Filter
Use ServletRegistrationBean to register ss000Action servlet into ss0001Filter used to remove /sp on url.

```
setFilter(ss0001Filter)
addServletRegistrationBeans(ss000Action ())
```

When submitting a url:

```
/sp/ss2000 => ss0001Filter => /ss2000 => ss2000 Controller processing => forward :/sp/ss1000
```

In the controller I have registered:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sp/ss1000"
```

However, a white screen error is occurring.

Please help me explain why this is so.

Is it because I registered a servlet that overrides the Dispatcher Servlet?

Is there any documentation that explains this?

What to do to solve it?

Comment: Hi. I'm assuming its because of your override as well. Can I ask why are you overriding the Dispatcher Servlet and not just creating your own controller?

Comment: Because I am converting from struts to springboot<br/>

In struts ss0001Servlet, it is extending ActionServlet<br/>
Configuration is as follows:<br/>


<servlet><br/>
<servlet-name>ss000Action </servlet-name><br/>
<servlet-class>ss0001Servlet </servlet-class><br/>
</servlet><br/>
<servlet-mapping><br/>
<servlet-name>ss000Action </servlet-name><br/>
<url-pattern>/sp/*</url-pattern><br/>
</servlet-mapping><br/>

Comment: Do you have a lot of servlets? It seems like it will still be easier to annotate every servlet with @Controller unless you have a lot of servlets.